# Adding data to a C buffer passed to a Python Ctypes callback

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C function in a DLL which is calling back to a Python function via ctypes.

The C function calls the function with the following prototype:

```
void GetData(u8 Buffer[], u16 Length);
```

Note that the buffer points to a static data array which is held in the DLL.

I've generated a Python function type for this as the following:

```
CFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p, c_int)
```

And my Python callback function is being called without any obvious problems.

My problem is, I can't work out how to get ctypes to add raw data to a buffer which is external to Python. Is there a way to define a ctypes string buffer and give it the address of the DLL's buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `memcpy` from libc. If your `c_char_p` is `buffer` and `c_int` is `bufferlen`:

```
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
content = 'My new content'
bufcontent = ctypes.create_string_buffer(content)
libc.memcpy(buffer. newcontent, min(len(content) + 1, bufferlen))
```

Same as you would do in C. (*note that i've used memcpy for possible binary content, but if you don't care about it, use `strncpy` instead*)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - you really pointed my along the right lines: - I found out that ctypes has a memmove function which wraps memcpy - so I didn't need to import libc. The only other thing I needed to do was to declare my function type as CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(c_char), c_int) rather than CFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p, c_int)
.